# mostrar lista de datos de firebase_database con flutter

Tags: flutter

Soy nuevo en flutter y estoy intregando firebase ya logre guardar datos y mostrarlos en la consola

Pero ahora quiero mostrarlos en un nuevo card
este es el codigo que llevo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: MyFirstApp(),
  ));
}
class MyFirstApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFirstAppState createState() => new _MyFirstAppState();
}
class _MyFirstAppState extends State<MyFirstApp> {
  final dataBaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Firebase"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("Guardar Archivos"),
              onPressed: (){
                GuardarArchivo();
              },
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("Ver Archivos"),
              onPressed: (){
                getData();
              },
            ),
            new Card(
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                 new Container(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                   child: Text(
                     ''' Nuevo Contenedor '''
                   ),
                 )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void GuardarArchivo(){
    dataBaseReference.child("1").set({
      'title':"New",
      'description':"Nueva"
    });
  }
  void getData(){

    dataBaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
      //print('Data: $snapshot.value');
      //new Text('$snapshot');
      for(var value in snapshot.value.values){
        print(value);
        //new Text(value);
      }

    });
  }
}
```

y este es un fragmento que encontre de codigo pero este usa firestore no firebase_database

```
return new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Flexible(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('chats').document('ROOM_1').collection('messages').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if (!snapshot.hasData){
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("No data")
              )
            );
          }

          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            reverse: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
              return ChatMessage(text: snapshot.data.documents[index]["messageField"]); //I just assumed that your ChatMessage class takes a parameter message text
            }
          );        
        }
      )
```

Agradecería su ayuda para poder completar este ejercicio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que migres a `Firestore`, pero para que puedas correr tu ejemplo, podrías usar este código:

```
      return StreamBuilder<Event>(
          stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('1').onValue,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("No data")));
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    snapshot.data.snapshot.value.toString(),
                  ),
                ); //I just assumed that your ChatMessage class takes a parameter message text
              },
            );
          },
        );
```

Comment: es mejor firestore

Comment: es pregunta o afirmación? si es pregunta, pues sí !

Comment: @dievoveloper pregunta.. Me falto el signo de interrogación empezare a ver firestore

Comment: dale, si te sirvió mi respuesta márcalo como resuelto, hay muchos ejemplos sobre firestore en la web.

Comment: el código con el que me apóyate va dentro d emi función getData